# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Cantidad' in 'NEW' (SQL: insert into `pedido` laravel 8

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Muy buenas, he estado con este problema el punto es que ya revise mi Modelo, inicialmente tenia 'Cantidad', pero lo he borrado y aun asi me da este error, no se donde viene esta variable
Sucede que al querer hacer el inserte me arroja este error, he buscado en cada archivo (controlador, modelo y la vista) y no existe 'Cantidad'
Esero me puedan ayudar, gracias y es un poco urgente, espero sus respuestas, ayuden a un pana en problemas, estuve viendo las preguntas similares, El nombre del modelo esta escrito correctamente, y el modelo no existe tal columna.
Mi Modelo

```
class PedidosF extends Model
{
    protected $table='pedido';

    protected $primaryKey='No_Pedido';

    public $timestamps=false;

    protected $fillable=[
        'No_pedido',
        'Fecha',
        'Descripcion',
        'Total',
        'Cancelado',
        'Credito',
        'Id_cliente',
        'Id_producto'
    ];

    protected $guarded =[

    ];
}
```

Mi controlador:

```
$name =  $request->descripcion;
            $description =  $request->cancelado;

            if(count($name) > count($description))
                $count = count($description);
            else $count = count($name);

            for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
                $data = array(
                    'Descripcion' => $name[$i],
                    'Cancelado' => $description[$i]
                );
                
                $insertData[] = $data;
            }

            PedidosF::insert($insertData);
```

Comment: Borraste `Cantidad` de la base de datos?

Comment: El problema está relacionado a la base de datos, prueba eliminando el campo manualmente de la base de datos como te indican arriba.
Si eso soluciona el problema, luego debes quitar el campo de las migraciones que se encuentran en la carpeta database>migrations

Comment: Si, lo Borre de la BD

Comment: No estoy usando migraciones, estoy manupulando una BD que ya existe

Comment: ¿Seguro que es el único insert que tienes en tu proyecto relacionado a esa tabla?

Answer (score 0):

El error menciona que 'Cantidad' ya no existe, y que la sentencia donde se encuentra 'Cantidad' SI EXISTE. 
Si usas herramientas como Visual Code, puedes buscar dentro del directorio completo para encontrar la susodicha 'Cantidad'.

Suerte!!!

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]

Comment: Eso quiero hacer, pero no dejan comentar como usted dice.

Comment: lee los enlaces.. necesitas 50 puntos de reputacion para poder hacerlo ;)....respetar las normas del sitio nos ayuda a todos ;)

Comment: Trabajamos para llegar a 50 ;) solo faltan 29 ptos mas.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas probable es que en tu form, tengas algun input con el nombre 'Cantidad' y los esta mandando en el request.

Te sugiero que revises tu campos, en caso de no encontrar referencia a ese campo, limpia tu caché de la aplicación.

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```